# Domain of exponential function

Tags: exponential-function

I have $$e^{\frac{x²+2}{x-1}}.$$
As the domain is the values for which the function is defined, I thought of making the denominator of the power equal to zero. So $x-1=0$ and the function is undefined at $x=1$. 
Thus the domain goes from $-\infty$ to $1$ and 1 to $\infty$. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes.  The function $e^x$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$, so any discontinuities would occur with the rational function exponent.

Comment: Yes, you are doing the right thing.

Comment: What about the horizontal asymptote? I know it is equal to 0 but i am not sure how to achieve it. I figured out that it may have something to to with the exponents.

Comment: There is a notation for this. The domain $D=\mathbb{R}\backslash\{1\}$. The backslash here means exclusion.

Comment: There is no $x$ such that $e^{\frac{x^2+2}{x-1}}=0$. We can see this because it implies $x^2+2=\ln(0)(x-1)$, and $\ln(0)$ is undefined

Comment: Okay, and i would like to know if anybody of you know if i can write this function in a graphing calculator to get the view of it. I have tried on a casio fx9750GII but it just seems to give me a straight line. How come? I am doing this excercise in order to sketch it. It is a past exam question.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you would write the domain as $x\ne 1, x\in\Bbb R$ (unless you're including complex numbers, but thats a different kettle of fish)